# ICN 3.0.x - Cannot update the width of a Custom editor

Tags: javascript, plugins, dojo, filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator

Following this [cool tutorial](http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/create-your-custom-attribute-editor-part-1/) of [Not Only an ECM Place](http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/), I aimed to write a custom Editor containing several elements and a field associated to the Property. This custom Editor will be installed through an ICN Plugin. Since the property is multi-valued, the editor will be embedded inside a **`PropertyTable`** editor.

Relevant files here are:

- The Plugin JavaScript file which will register the plugin (in the global `ControlRegistry` object of ICN)
- The custom Editor JavaScript file which will extend both the custom Widget and the `_EditorMixin` class which maps the Widget to the Property
- The custom Widget JavaScript file with a dojo HTML template

Below the attempt to make the Editor width resizable. In the Editor registration code, I used a `DimensionSetting` and tried to override onSettingChanged() to make the Editor Widget resizable:

```
require([ /* [...] */],
        function(lang, ) {
            var editorId = "theWannaBeResizeableEditor";
            ControlRegistry.editors.editorConfigs[editorId] = {
                label: "A dummy label",
                editorClass: AWannaBeResizeableEditor,
                settings:
                [
                    {
                        name: "width",
                        controlClass: DimensionSetting,
                        controlParams: {
                            label: resources.styleSettingsLabel.width,
                            help: resources.styleSettingsHelp.width
                        },
                        defaultValue: "100%",
                        // And here begins the problem...
                        onSettingChanged: function(helper, width) {
                            // Tried to resize the Widget : FAIL
                        }
                    } // [...]
                ]
            }
        });
```

I tried, amongst others, this implementation:

```
onSettingChanged: function(helper, width) {
  helper.updateSetting("width", width);
  helper.widget._adjustSizing && helper.widget._adjustSizing();
  helper.widget.view.resize();
}
```

It didn't work. The Redbooks aren't very talkative about custom Widgets, so - except the tutorial I mentioned previously, it's hard to find information except by "reverse engineering", a big word for JavaScript objects exploration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I wrote a similar answer in another place.*

After a bunch of find, grep, less (I strongly advise to install Cygwin for this kind of investigation, it really helps). I figured out that some standard Editor Settings widgets relies on **`TextBoxEditorSettings`** to make their width updatable. This widget can be found here: `pvd/widget/editors/settings/TextBoxEditorSetting.js`

TextBox, for example, is one of them. The association between **`TextBoxEditorSettings`** and **`TextBox`** editor can be found in `pvd/widget/registry/BasicHelperConfiguration.js`:

```
define(
    [/* [...] */],
    function (declare,
          /* [...] */,
          textBoxEditorSettings,
          /* [...] */) {
        return {
            editors: {
                editorConfigs: {
                    // [...]
                    "textBox": {
                        settings: textBoxEditorSettings
                    } // [...]
                }
            }
        }
     }
);
```

**`TextBoxEditorSettings`** manages the case of an Editor embedded inside a **`PropertyTable`**. Instead of configuring the width configuration editing from scratch I tried to reuse and extend it.

If we need to add other settings (text, etc.). we should not append them **directly** to **`TextBoxEditorSettings`**, otherwise all editors configured with it would get these settings too, especially **`TextBox`**, which is not what we want. Instead, we'll use a **shallow copy**, invoking `slice()`.

```
require(
    [
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "ecm/model/configuration/ControlRegistry",
        // [...] Include below all the settings editor you need
        "pvd/widget/editors/settings/TextBoxEditorSettings",
        // Below your custom template
        "AWannaBeResizeableEditorPluginDojo/editors/AWannaBeResizeableEditor",
        // Below for translation support of TextBoxEditorSettings
        "dojo/i18n!pvd/nls/common"
    ],
    function(lang, ControlRegistry, TextBoxSetting,
             TextBoxEditorSettings, AWannaBeResizeableEditor,
             resources) {
        var editorId = "aWannaBeResizeableEditor";

        // Perform a shallow copy to avoid conflicts
        var editorSettings = TextBoxEditorSettings.slice();

        // Additional setting editors
        // Repeat this block for all further setting editor needed
        /// 1. Definition
        var anotherSettingEditor = {
            // [...]
        };
        /// 2. Insertion
        editorSettings.unshift(anotherSettingEditor);
        /// End of this block

        // Registration in the editor configurations...
        ControlRegistry.editors.editorConfigs[editorId] = {
            label: "A Wannabe Resizable Editor",
            editorClass: AWannaBeResizeableEditor,
            settings: editorSettings
        }

        // Registring the widget in the right mapping type
        // [...]
    }
);
```

Then write your template to make it as easily as possible resizable. I designed it to make the editor resizable from the top node. I named the attach point of the top node `oneuiBaseNode` so no need to overrride `adjustWidth()`. and `resetWidth()`.

```
<div class="searchBoxFillerWidget"
     data-dojo-attach-point="oneuiBaseNode">
    <!--
         Write here HTML code relatively resizeable
         to the top node.
    -->
</div>
```